# Replicating slider in multiple views

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uislider

I'm very new to objective-c and programming in general, and just started building a tab-based app in xcode. I have three view controllers and a slider in each of the views. I want the sliders in the second and third view to copy the position (and therefore the value) of the slider in the first view - and vice versa. So that irrespective of which view the user is at, it looks as though there is only one slider throughout.

I’m pretty sure there must be a simpler way to go about this. I hope I’ve explained my issue adequately.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do your sliders do? Do they change a preference, or a property of an object? I'm wondering where the value is stored, if at all, so that it can be referenced by the other sliders.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few solutions you can implement.

1. You can create one slider and have a reference to it in some type of singleton object like the AppDelegate and pass it around to the respective views adding as a subview. Since a view can only have one super view your are safe.
2. You can use NSNotifications to notify each of the sliders that a value has changed. NSNotifications allow you to pass in an NSDictionary call userInfo so you can pass values around.

My personal opinion is that number 1 is cleaner, NSNotifications are heavy and there might be a slight delay on when things actually get updated.

Answer (score 0):

Add following target to your slider

```
- (IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender 
{ 
    // fire notification here
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"SliderValueChanged" object:nil];
}
```

and in your other view controllers, you can add observer for "SliderValueChanged"

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                               selector:@selector(onSliderValueChanged:) 
                               name:"SliderValueChanged" object:nil];

- (void)onSliderValueChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
     // Adjust your respective view controller's slider here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to store your UISlider value in NSUserDefaults when it changes. Now in every controllers ViewWillAppear method you can get that value from NSUserDefaults and set it for your UISlider. That way no matter which controller the user is looking at it will show the same value for them.